# How select an item from the drop-down list without using scrolling and simulate user activity - Drag in TestCafe Studio?

Tags: testing, scroll, drag-and-drop, automated-tests, testcafe

I use Testcafe Studio to write tests.

There is a long drop-down list with elements. The item to select is out of view. Interested in how you can implement its selection without using scrolling (without using the built-in On-Page Actions: Drag). Maybe you can somehow implement it using functions or a script?

Specific task: in this form (https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) there is a drop-down list of the "Platform/Category:" field. Using TestCafe Studio, I need to write a test that selects the value "Native" from the list without using horizontal scrolling.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

try creating a function like this,

```
async selectDropDown(dropDownEle, valueToSelect){    
        await t.click(dropDownEle);
        await t.click(await dropDownEle.find('option[title="' + valueToSelect +'"]'));
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, what about dropDownEle in this case? In the task that I described at the very beginning above (with a specific list and an element necessary for selection), what should I specify in `' option[title="' + valueToSelect +'"]'));` ? Thanks. By the way, do I understand correctly that we should convert the recorded test to JS and add it there instead of using the built-in TestCafe Studio Statements = Define Function?

Comment: In your case valueToSelect would be 'Native'. And dropDownEle would be the selector for the "Platform/Category:" field.
You can use Custom scripts to do this
[link](https://docs.devexpress.com/TestCafeStudio/401265/test-actions/custom-scripts#run-testcafe-script)

Comment: I try this, but does not work: `async selectDropDown(TechnologyOid, Native){    
        await t.click(TechnologyOid);
        await t.click(await TechnologyOid.find('option[title="' + Native +'"]'));
    }` What's wrong?

Comment: Can you post the html code for the drop down.
And while using custom script, since you want to choose a particular value from drop down use, 
`await t.click(TechnologyOid); await t.click(await TechnologyOid.find('option[title="' + Native +'"]'));`

Comment: the character limit does not allow it. here is a link to this drop-down list: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create

Comment: The example I mentioned is for handling common type of drop downs. There is a small mistake in the last comment. The correct code would be 
`await t.click(TechnologyOid); await t.click(await TechnologyOid.find('option[title="Native"]'));`
However drop down in your case is different. I'll try look in to the link. Thanks